# Error While connecting to MQTT Broker using JavaScript MQTT Client With Websockets

Tags: javascript, mqtt, iot

I am working with MQTT, when I am trying to connect to mosquitto_sub I am able to connect but When I am trying to connect through JavaScript MQTT Client With Websockets then I am getting an error `AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out`.

Here is my code :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Mosquitto Websockets</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.2/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
 var host = "eu.thethings.network";
 var username = "sr-ops-rtr-XX";
 var password = "ttn-account-v2.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 var topic = "/devices/+/up";
 var useTLS = "sr-ops-rtr-01";
 cleansession = "";
 var port = 10;
    var mqtt;
    var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
    function MQTTconnect() {
 if (typeof path == "undefined") {
  path = '/devices/up';
 }
 mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(
   host,
   port,
   path,
   "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10)
 );
 
        var options = {
            timeout: 10,
            //useSSL: useTLS,
            //cleanSession: true,
            onSuccess: onConnect,
            onFailure: function (message) {
    console.log(message);
                $('#status').val("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage + "Retrying");
                setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
            }
        };
        mqtt.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
        mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
        if (username != null) {
            options.userName = username;
            options.password = password;
        }
        console.log("Host="+ host + ", port=" + port + ", path=" + path +  " username=" + username + " password=" + password);
  console.log(options);
        mqtt.connect(options);
    }
    function onConnect() {
  alert("connected");
        $('#status').val('Connected to ' + host + ':' + port + path);
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic
        mqtt.subscribe(topic, {qos: 0});
        $('#topic').val(topic);
    }
    function onConnectionLost(response) {
        setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
        $('#status').val("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage + ". Reconnecting");
    };
    function onMessageArrived(message) {
        var topic = message.destinationName;
        var payload = message.payloadString;
        $('#ws').prepend('<li>' + topic + ' = ' + payload + '</li>');
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        MQTTconnect();
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mosquitto Websockets</h1>
    <div>
        <div>Subscribed to <input type='text' id='topic' disabled />
        Status: <input type='text' id='status' size="80" disabled /></div>

        <ul id='ws' style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move your **MQTTconnect();** into body element

Comment: may be some connection failure error. Try test your broker connection using **MQTTLen** or **MQTTBox** with chrome extension.

Comment: Are you sure the Things Network supports MQTT over Websockets? The Doc (https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/applications/mqtt/api.html) makes no mention of it. (also port 10 looks wrong)

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page a call to MQTTconnect is made ( bottom of the page in code above).

```
<body>
<h1>Mosquitto Websockets</h1>
<div>
    <div>Subscribed to <input type='text' id='topic' disabled />
    Status: <input type='text' id='status' size="80" disabled /></div>

    <ul id='ws' style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"></ul>
 </div>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      MQTTconnect();
    });
</body>
```

Comment: I am able to call the function that's not a problem I believe

Comment: may be some connection failure error. Try test your broker connection using MQTTLen or MQTTBox with chrome extension.

Comment: And you have written the jQuery in HTML body without script declared. Correct it